# How to reset a field in swing after dispose() is called

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a JFrame and I have created an object to open it and close it all around my project. This means I am using only one object for that JFrame.

When I call `dispose()` method to close that frame I expect it to be reset to a new JFrame on next `setVisible(true)` call. But i can still see the fields filled with value from the previous `setVisible(true)` call even after i called `dispose()` on closing it.

How do I flush the stored values from that frame so that I get a new form when i call `setVisible(true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a [WindowListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html):

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
         MyJFrame frame = (MyJFrame) e.getSource();
         frame.someTextField.setText("");
         ...
    }
});
```

This isn't tested but should be close enough to get you started.

Comment: thank you.. Actually i am looking for any methods similar to dispose() but if there is no other way then i have to try these methods. Currently i am using the method you just told me..

Comment: There isn't any built-in method that will automatically do it, but you can override `dispose` or `setVisible` and clear your fields there after calling the parent class's implementation if you'd rather do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

dispose() doesn't reset your components but you can create new JFrame manually:

```
previous.setVisible(false);
previous = new JFrame();
previous.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: but i might need to open the frame like this 1000 times a day.. if i keep on creating new frames like this will it affect the performance ?

Comment: Performance - I don't think so but you can test it. Memory - if you haven't any references to old frames then GC will removes it correctly. My second proposition is to manually clearing your components: e.g: setText(""); etc.

Comment: While technically true, it can still degrade performance, since there's no guarantee when the GC will run.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime