# Remove Top-Level Container on Runtime

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jdialog

Unfortunately, it looks like this recently closed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305170/is-really-not-possible-remove-on-runtime-any-of-jdialog-or-jwindow) was not well understood. Here is the typical output:

```
run:
    Trying to Remove JDialog
    Remove Cycle Done :-)
    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers
JFrame
JDialog
    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. 1
 -----------------------------------------------------------
    Trying to Remove JDialog
    Remove Cycle Done :-)
    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers
JFrame
JDialog
    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. 2
 -----------------------------------------------------------
    Trying to Remove JDialog
    Remove Cycle Done :-)
    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers
JFrame
JDialog
    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. 3
 -----------------------------------------------------------
    Trying to Remove JDialog
    Remove Cycle Done :-)
    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers
JFrame
JDialog
*** End of Cycle Without Success, Exit App ***
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

I'll try asking this question again: How can I k*i*l*l on Runtime the first-opened top-Level `Container`, and help with closing for me one of Swing NightMares?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RemoveDialogOnRuntime extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int contID = 1;
    private boolean runProcess;
    private int top = 20;
    private int left = 20;
    private int maxLoop = 0;

    public RemoveDialogOnRuntime() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setTitle("Remove Dialog On Runtime");
        setLocation(150, 150);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        Point loc = this.getLocation();
        top += loc.x;
        left += loc.y;
        AddNewDialog();
    }

    private void AddNewDialog() {
        DialogRemove firstDialog = new DialogRemove();
        remWins();
    }

    private void remWins() {
        runProcess = true;
        Thread th = new Thread(new RemTask());
        th.setDaemon(false);
        th.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        th.start();
    }

    private class RemTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (runProcess) {
                Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();
                for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
                    if (wins[i] instanceof JDialog) {
                        System.out.println("    Trying to Remove JDialog");
                        wins[i].setVisible(false);
                        wins[i].dispose();
                        WindowEvent windowClosing = new WindowEvent(wins[i], WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
                        wins[i].dispatchEvent(windowClosing);
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(windowClosing);
                        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        runtime.gc();
                        runtime.runFinalization();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(RemoveDialogOnRuntime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                wins = null;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("    Remove Cycle Done :-)");
                        Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalization();
                        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                        runProcess = false;
                    }
                });
            }
            pastRemWins();
        }
    }

    private void pastRemWins() {
        System.out.println("    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers");
        Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();
        for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
            if (wins[i] instanceof JFrame) {
                System.out.println("JFrame");
                wins[i].setVisible(true);
            } else if (wins[i] instanceof JDialog) {
                System.out.println("JDialog");
                wins[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        if (wins.length > 1) {
            wins = null;
            maxLoop++;
            if (maxLoop <= 3) {
                System.out.println("    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. " + maxLoop);
                System.out.println(" -----------------------------------------------------------");
                remWins();
            } else {
                System.out.println(" -----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("*** End of Cycle Without Success, Exit App ***");
                closeMe();
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeMe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    private class DialogRemove extends JDialog {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        DialogRemove(final Frame parent) {
            super(parent, "SecondDialog " + (contID++));
            setLocation(top, left);
            top += 20;
            left += 20;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        private DialogRemove() {
            setTitle("SecondDialog " + (contID++));
            setLocation(top, left);
            top += 20;
            left += 20;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                RemoveDialogOnRuntime superConstructor = new RemoveDialogOnRuntime();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel, as I said before, set the reference to `null`, then it will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @mre :-) I really appreciated your input in my previous post for remove reference to Array, and tried to remove that by Object from Class(es), but still there exist one JDialog and one JWindow... :-)

Comment: @mre I can't set any reference to null only twice wins = null;

Comment: I'm not coded, nor developer, just Java Fans who couldn't accepted state that first JDialog (plus JWindow if displaed) still exist in Runtime and I can't to remove that, (for this purpose I bought on last week OneRitchUnNamed JavaTools too, no way there, then now I to trying that to solve with standard way)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: +1 I've had the same nightmare running heavyweight apps in a loop from the command line.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for change, nothing missed :-) +1, @camickr thanks for good hint +1, as I tried my code works for Top-Level Containers only in case if are there more then one JDialog or JWindow, first added Container pretty ignored, :-)

Comment: Your sample code violates the "golden EDT rule": never call a Swing method from another Thread than EDT. When you call dispose() you are not in the EDT! Same remark for setVisible() in pastRemWins().

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you could specify what you mean by "removing the container", e.g. remove OS resources for the window, make the window hidden, collect memory used by Java objects used by the window...

Comment: `dispose()` is clearly documented as releasing all OS resources used by the window, and thus NOT the java part of it! Javadoc even mentions that calling `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` will recreate new OS resources to make the window displayable.

Comment: @jfpoilpret please see my reply to Howard's post, anyway if you have got any hack, please post here your view, because in this case I pretty sure that EDT must be violated, I tried that, otherwise effects are variable, sometimes stay alive two JDialogs, sometimes only one, I really don't know first JDialog stay alive forever ...

Comment: @mKorbel see my newly posted answer, that doesn't need to violate any EDT rule.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Invoking [`dispose()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) allows the host platform to reclaim memory consumed by the heavyweight peer, but it can't do so until *after* the `WINDOW_CLOSING` event is processed on the `EventQueue`. Even then, `gc()` is a suggestion.

Addendum: Another way to see the nightmare is via a profiler. Running the example below with `jvisualvm`, one can see that periodic collection never *quite* returns to baseline. I've exaggerated the vertical axis by starting with an artificially small heap. Additional examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916028/how-do-i-get-appcontext-to-release-awt-components-so-they-can-be-garbage-collecte/5918785#5918785). When memory is very limited, I've used two approaches:

- Emergent: Loop from the command line, starting a new VM each time.
- Urgent: Eliminate the heavyweight component entirely, running headless and composing in a `BufferedImage` using 2D graphics and lightweight components only.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407 */
public class DialogClose extends JDialog {

    public DialogClose(int i) {
        this.setTitle("Dialog " + String.valueOf(i));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 200));
    }

    private void display() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        passSomeTime();
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(
            this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        this.dispose();
        passSomeTime();
    }

    private void passSomeTime() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int count = 0;
                while (true) {
                    new DialogClose(count++).display();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I have completely reworked your example:

- I have simplified what was not needed (`setLocation()`, unused constructor...)
- I have removed the code that triggers a WINDOW_CLOSING event (useless)
- I have removed code that resets all windows to visible again (which would prevent GC on them)
- I have used a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of a `Thread` for disposing of the dialog
- I have used a `Thread` for forcing GC (not a good idea in the EDT)
- I have modified the final success criterion to check that `Window.getWindows()` is **2** (not **1**), because in Swing, if you open a dialog with no parent, then a special invisible frame will be created to use it as parent (for all ownerless dialogs actually), once created, that frame **cannot** be removed.

The resulting snippet follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RemoveDialogOnRuntime extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean runProcess;
    private int maxLoop = 0;
    private Timer timer;

    public RemoveDialogOnRuntime() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setTitle("Remove Dialog On Runtime");
        setLocation(150, 150);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        addNewDialog();
    }

    private void addNewDialog() {
        DialogRemove firstDialog = new DialogRemove();
        remWins();
    }

    private void remWins() {
        runProcess = true;
        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (runProcess) {
                    for (Window win: Window.getWindows()) {
                        if (win instanceof JDialog) {
                            System.out.println("    Trying to Remove JDialog");
                            win.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("    Remove Cycle Done :-)");
                    runProcess = false;
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                        }
                    }.start();
                } else {
                    pastRemWins();
                    runProcess = true;
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void pastRemWins() {
        System.out.println("    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers");
        Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();
        for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
            if (wins[i] instanceof JFrame) {
                System.out.println("JFrame");
            } else if (wins[i] instanceof JDialog) {
                System.out.println("JDialog");
            } else {
                System.out.println(wins[i].getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
        // We must expect 2 windows here: this (RemoveDialogOnRuntime) and the parent of all parentless dialogs
        if (wins.length > 2) {
            wins = null;
            maxLoop++;
            if (maxLoop <= 3) {
                System.out.println("    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. " + maxLoop);
                System.out.println(" -----------------------------------------------------------");
                remWins();
            } else {
                System.out.println(" -----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("*** End of Cycle Without Success, Exit App ***");
                closeMe();
            }
        } else {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    private void closeMe() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private class DialogRemove extends JDialog {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private DialogRemove() {
            setTitle("SecondDialog");
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                RemoveDialogOnRuntime superConstructor = new RemoveDialogOnRuntime();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The important conclusions are:

- You can't remove the invisible frame created by Swing as parent of all ownerless dialogs
- You have to force a GC for the disposed dialog to be removed from `Window.getWindows()` (that one looks like a bug to me but I think the reason is that Swing keeps a `WeakReference` to all windows, and this `WeakReference` is not released until a GC has occurred.

Hope this gives a clear and complete answer to your problem.

Comment: thanks for your valuable input 1+, everything is clear, but after removed useless methods you lost effect from remove 2D Graphics from Top-Level Containers on level of UsedMemory(by trashgod), sure there still exist another option how to decrease used memory, JDialog#WINDOW_CLOSING plus JDialog#removeAll == remove RootPane :-) then contents of JDialog (JWindow) will be translucent :-), result still remaining in Java6 from any ofTop_layoput is possible remove 2D Graphics only, thanks

Answer (score 8):

with the intent to blow away all doubts about EDT and confirm trashgod Updated suggestion, then output to the console is

```
run:
7163 KB used before GC
    Trying to Remove JDialog
    Remove Cycle Done :-)
405 KB used after GC
    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers
JFrame
JDialog
    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. 1
 -----------------------------------------------------------
3274 KB used before GC
    Trying to Remove JDialog
    Remove Cycle Done :-)
403 KB used after GC
    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers
JFrame
JDialog
    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. 2
 -----------------------------------------------------------
3271 KB used before GC
    Trying to Remove JDialog
    Remove Cycle Done :-)
406 KB used after GC
    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers
JFrame
JDialog
    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. 3
 -----------------------------------------------------------
3275 KB used before GC
    Trying to Remove JDialog
    Remove Cycle Done :-)
403 KB used after GC
    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers
JFrame
JDialog
 -----------------------------------------------------------
*** End of Cycle Without Success, Exit App ***
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 26 seconds)
```

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RemoveDialogOnRuntime extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int contID = 1;
    private boolean runProcess;
    private int top = 20;
    private int left = 20;
    private int maxLoop = 0;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer = null;

    public RemoveDialogOnRuntime() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setTitle("Remove Dialog On Runtime");
        setLocation(150, 150);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        Point loc = this.getLocation();
        top += loc.x;
        left += loc.y;
        AddNewDialog();
    }

    private void AddNewDialog() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DialogRemove firstDialog = new DialogRemove();
                startAA();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startAA() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(5000, updateAA());
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateAA() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
                if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                    Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            remWins();
                        }
                    };
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
                } else {
                    Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            remWins();
                        }
                    };
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void remWins() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long total = runtime.totalMemory();
        long free = runtime.freeMemory();
        long max = runtime.maxMemory();
        long used = total - free;
        System.out.println(Math.round(used / 1e3) + " KB used before GC");
        Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();
        for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
            if (wins[i] instanceof JDialog) {
                System.out.println("    Trying to Remove JDialog");
                wins[i].setVisible(false);
                wins[i].dispose();
                WindowEvent windowClosing = new WindowEvent(wins[i], WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
                wins[i].dispatchEvent(windowClosing);
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(windowClosing);
                runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                runtime.gc();
                runtime.runFinalization();
            }
        }
        wins = null;
        System.out.println("    Remove Cycle Done :-)");
        runtime.runFinalization();
        runtime.gc();
        runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        total = runtime.totalMemory();
        free = runtime.freeMemory();
        max = runtime.maxMemory();
        used = total - free;
        System.out.println(Math.round(used / 1e3) + " KB used after GC");
        startOO();
    }

    private void startOO() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(5000, updateOO());
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateOO() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
                timer.stop();
                if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                    Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {//really contraproductive just dealayed

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pastRemWins();
                        }
                    };
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
                } else {
                    Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pastRemWins();
                        }
                    };
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void pastRemWins() {
        System.out.println("    Checking if still exists any of TopLayoutContainers");
        Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();
        for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
            if (wins[i] instanceof JFrame) {
                System.out.println("JFrame");
                wins[i].setVisible(true);
            } else if (wins[i] instanceof JDialog) {
                System.out.println("JDialog");
                wins[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        if (wins.length > 1) {
            wins = null;
            maxLoop++;
            if (maxLoop <= 3) {
                System.out.println("    Will Try Remove Dialog again, CycleNo. " + maxLoop);
                System.out.println(" -----------------------------------------------------------");
                remWins();
            } else {
                System.out.println(" -----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("*** End of Cycle Without Success, Exit App ***");
                closeMe();
            }
        }
        startAA();
    }

    private void closeMe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    private class DialogRemove extends JDialog {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        DialogRemove(final Frame parent) {
            super(parent, "SecondDialog " + (contID++));
            setLocation(top, left);
            top += 20;
            left += 20;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        private DialogRemove() {
            setTitle("SecondDialog " + (contID++));
            setLocation(top, left);
            top += 20;
            left += 20;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                RemoveDialogOnRuntime superConstructor = new RemoveDialogOnRuntime();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 It makes some sense that the memory for heavyweight components can't be reliably reclaimed until the JVM exits.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you question  is about "garbage collection" or about how to identify dialogs that are visible.

You can't control when garbage collection is done. Invoking the gc() method is only a suggestion.

If you want to ignore "disposed" dialogs then you can use the isDisplayable() method to check its status.

With the following program I got some interesting results. First change I made was to add some components to the dialog so that more resources would be used for each dialog which would increase the chance that the resources would be garbage collected.

On my machine I found that if I

a) create 5 dialogs
b) close the dialogs
c) create 5 dialogs

Then the first 5 appear to be garbage collected.

However if I create 5, then close then create 1, then close, it doesn't seem to work.

Bottom line is you can't depend on when garbage collection will be done, so I suggest you use the isDisplayable() method to determine how to do your processing. The "Display Dialogs" button uses this method as part of the displayed output.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public static int count;

    public DialogSSCCE()
    {
        JButton display = new JButton("Display Dialogs");
        display.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Display Dialogs");

                for (Window window: Window.getWindows())
                {
                    if (window instanceof JDialog)
                    {
                        JDialog dialog = (JDialog)window;
                        System.out.println("\t" + dialog.getTitle() + " " + dialog.isDisplayable());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        add( display );

        JButton open = new JButton("Create Dialog");
        open.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Create Dialog");

                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

                for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                {
                    dialog.add( new JTextField("some text") );
                }

                dialog.setTitle("Dialog " + count++);
                dialog.setLocation(count * 25, count * 25);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("\tCreated " + dialog.getTitle());
            }
        });
        add( open );

        JButton close = new JButton("Close Dialogs");
        close.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Close Dialogs");

                for (Window window: Window.getWindows())
                {
                    if (window instanceof JDialog)
                    {
                        JDialog dialog = (JDialog)window;
                        System.out.println("\tClosing " + dialog.getTitle());
                        dialog.dispose();
                    }
                }

                Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            }
        });
        add( close );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DialogSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new DialogSSCCE() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a timeout defined in the `AppContext` before some resources will be released finally. This is set to something like 5 seconds. Thus if you wait for another five seconds also the context will dispose the (last) reference to your dialog.

```
wins = null;
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: it seems to nothing changed, I tried all possible woodoo... :-) +1, really if you'll create more than one JDialog every are killed by gc, first stay alive (same for JWindow), if you'll create tons of JDialogs and JWindows, then every are disposed and GC'ed, but first of JDialogs and JWindows too stay live forever :-), eeerrrggghhhht...

Comment: @mKorbel It did indeed release the last window in my test and only the JFrame was remaining. Plus an additional hidden frame which you do not print in your loop. Thus wins.length is still two!