# AWT-EventQueue thread and AWT-Shutdown thread not shutting down

Tags: multithreading, swing, awt, awt-eventqueue

The AWT-EventQueue thread and AWT-Shutdown thread are not shutting down in our application.  Is there a debugging technique for finding out why they are not?  Any special things to look for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean that the JVM doesn't exit properly after closing all windows, then look at the following points:

- check that ALL windows have been disposed properly, not just simply made invisible; that includes the invisible window created by Swing (or AWT) as the owner of ownerless dialogs. For this you can check `Window.getWindows()`
- make sure you have no active `Thread` (except daemons) after disposing of all windows
- ensure that your application was not launched by Java Web Start, because in this case you must call `System.exit(0)` (that's a known bug of JWS)

Hope this helps answer your question.

Besides, there was also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime) recently about garbage collection of Swing windows.