# How could I get the number of visible windows of my app?

Tags: java, swing, window, awt, jframe

*Or more exact:*

I need to know on a window close event, if any other window is still visible.

If not, `System.exit(0)` would be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for answers. With this help I managed to get a working solution:

*Strange, it doesn't works with `windowClosed`. Only works with `windowClosing`.*

### Code

```
public final class CloseOnLastWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("\tCLOSING!!!");

        int nRelevant = 0;
        for (Window w : Window.getWindows()) {
            // get only visible windows, except the one being closed
            if (w != e.getWindow() && w.isVisible()) {
                System.out.println("\tRELEVANT: " + w);
                ++nRelevant;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\tirrelevant: " + w);
            }
        }

        if (nRelevant == 0) {
            System.out.println("\tEXIT!!!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1)    `I need to know on a window close event`

there are [WindowConstants](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html) and [WindowEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html)

2) `if any other window is still visible.`

you can get number of [Top-Level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) by using `Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();` for testing their visibility or by adding [WindowStateListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html)

some important notice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if(Frame.getFrames().length == 0) {
    // work here.
}
```

(`Frame` is `java.awt.Frame`, that is the parent of `JFrame`, so you will capture them, too).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know on a window close event, if any other window is still visible. If not, System.exit(0) would be called.

Just use:

```
frame.dispose();
```

When the last window is close the JVM will exit automatically.

Or when you create you frames and dialogs use:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrema.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: "When the last window is close the JVM will exit automatically": that's true only if not used with Java Web Start, and provided you have no non-daemon running thread. You also may have problems when using modal dialogs for which Swing opens a parent frame that you need to dispose manually.

Comment: "frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrema.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);": this doesn't answer OP's question, he wants that the LAST closed frame exits the application, not just any of them.

Comment: @jfpoilpret -- Good objection, by accident, I was going to use Webstart.

Comment: @jfpoilpret, Hmm, I just updated my [Alpha Container](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) webstart app to use "DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE". When I click the "Launch" button the app starts and it shows up on the Windows Task Manager. When I click on the close button it closes and is removed from the Windows Task Manager. Does this not mean the JVM has exited?

Comment: @camickr yeah, that's strange, maybe they've fixed that bug in recent Java Plugins? Kirill had written a good post about it a few years ago: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/01/14/when-dispose_on_close-met-webstart.html

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find the original bug ID, to check its status. If someone has got the reference, please post it in a comment!