# Escape button with Jpanel or JFrame or Dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, key-bindings, jdialog

I am creating an application in which any opened **Jpanel** or **JFrame** or **Dialog** should be closed on striking **Escape** button of the keyboard.

If I open any panel and direct hit Escape button that it is closed successfully without any problem.. but when I am trying to close it using Escape key after doing something in that JPanel or JFrame or Dialog, It is unable to close.

Please assist me if I am doing any thing wrong

Thanks in advance...

My method is

```
public static void addKeyBinding(JComponent c, final Object promptControl) {
         debugLogger.debug("Start Escape Key Binding ");

         Action escape = new AbstractAction() {

             {
                 putValue(NAME, "escape");
             }

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 try {
                     JComponent source = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                     Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(source);
                     window.dispose();
                     Dialog dialog = (Dialog) source.getFocusCycleRootAncestor();
                     dialog.dispose();
                     debugLogger.debug("source = " + source.getClass().getName() 
                             + "\n"
                             + "source.focusCycleRootAncestor = "
                             + source.getFocusCycleRootAncestor().getClass().getName());
                 } catch (Exception ex) {
                     errorLogger.error("Exception caught while closing the window." + x.toString());
                 }
             }
         };
         Object name = escape.getValue(Action.NAME);
         c.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), name);
         c.getActionMap().put(name, escape);
         debugLogger.debug("End Escape Key Binding ");
     }
```

Comment: Please read the tags you add to posts.  [tag:escaping] (as used at SO) is not what you seem to think.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  you have remove dot or doubledot

Comment: Maybe WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW: c.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), name);

Comment: @Korhan Öztürk : No it does not throw any exception. Either it doesn't enter in actionPerformed block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of to create bunch of [Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) on Runtime

2) Re_use `Top-Level Containers` by removing its content, because these containers are [presents in the memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)

3) if you'll re_use [JDialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) then you have to call only `setVisible(true/fasle)`, better would be wrap visibilities to the `invokeLater()` to add this event to [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

EDIT

```
window/dialog.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
   .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESC"), "myAction");
window/dialog.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("myAction", new AbstractAction() {...});
```

Comment: thanks mKorbal for the reply. can you provide more information that how to do it? I don't have any idea.

Comment: aaaah I see that, for listening from KeEyBindings you have to add RootPane and Focused, please see my edit

Comment: -1 for the bullets (random noise), +1 for the rootPane's keyBindings, that is zero until you edit and remove the noise :-)

Comment: c.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), name);

Now It's woking fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), "closeTheDialog");
    getRootPane().getActionMap().put("closeTheDialog",
            new AbstractAction() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 8360999630557775801L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //This should be replaced by the action you want to perform
                    cancel.doClick();
                }
            });
```

Was sorted with that. Thank to [mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel)