# Are native screen resources automatically released when the JVM exits?

Tags: java, swing, jvm

If doing `System.exit(1)` from a Swing application, are native resources related to the graphics automatically released ? If I add a `myFrame.dispose()` with `myFrame` being the sole
top-level container in the app, can I be sure not to get the annoying behavoiur seen in some
non-java GUI using programs where part of the GUI state will stick frozen to the screen when exiting abruptly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything owned by a process is released when the process exits, unless you are talking about pathological operating systems like Netware 3 & 4.

Answer (score 2):

- Top-Level Containers never GC'ed, because missed method finalize()
- In this context `JFrame.dispose()` do nothing, this container is still present in UsedMemory, un_changed, untill current JVM instance exits,
- you can returns UsedMemerory by removing it contents, notice remove anything from `ContentPane`, otherwise `(RootPane` removed) your container stays translucent, only with visible `ToolBar` and `Borders`,
- all Window are always accesible and re_usable, you can test that by `Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows();` throught whole application lifecycle
- before re_using test container for `isDisplayable()`
- everything important [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)

then

1) don't create lots of Top-Level containers,

2) re_use container that exist

3) only `Object` that lost all referencies could be `GC'ed`