# Java swing gui memory allocation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, memory

Hi I was wondering if there is a way to set a jbutton to do the equivalent of setdefaultcloseoperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) because I dont understand how a frame object is eligible for collection if it still has listeners when the frame is set invisible. I can send code if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Explain a bit more. I can't see what you're asking here.

Comment: Just in the `actionPerformed(...)` method of your so called `JButton` write `frameObject.dispose();`, that will give you, your equivalent behaviour :-)

Comment: Hehe, You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Top Level Containers (`JFrame`, `JDialog` ...) miss implemetations for `finalize()`, [then they are never GC'd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)
- equivalent for `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is only `setVisible(false)`
- you can returns all Top Level Containers from method `Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();`
- you can remove only all `JComponents` from `ContentPane`, for return used memory back

EDIT

- only visible container with `Focus` can listening or firing events from [Swing Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/api.html)

Comment: +1, this info is always true, no one has the power to control GARBAGE COLLECTION :-), but wont' writing dispose(), will atleast make it available for the GC to collect it, though only JVM can tell as to when will that happen.

Comment: ya thats what i thought. so does setVisible(false) leave the frames listeners open? thus not making the frame eligible for gc?

Comment: that make sense. just so i know i have understood your edit, is Focus what setVisible(bool) turns on and off?

Answer (score 1):

```
addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                   myframe.dispose();
                   }
            });
```