# Dialog server die

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have a weird behavior with the JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...) method (and other methods of JJOptionPane).
The dialogs created never seem to die. When I call Window.getWindows() after the dialog has disappeared, the number of windows has increased!

Test this program and you see what I mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JButton button = new JButton("Show Dialog");
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter some text : ");
                System.out.println(Window.getWindows().length);
            }
        });
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Someone understand what happens?

`Window.getWindows()` returns always every [Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) that are created (without containers returns `!isDisplayable`) in the `current JVM`, these containers never gone from `JVM memory`,  nor be `GC'ed`, because they are came as resources from `Native OS`, [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)

Comment: `Why` do you backtick `stuff` that's `not actually code` in your answers? We have **`bold`** `and` *`italics`* for that.