# Java Memory Leak: WDialogPeer is the only strong reference - why wont it GC?

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, awt, yourkit

I'm doing some profiling on a legacy Java product and hunting down memory leaks using YourKit.  I'm plugging quite a lot - but I keep coming across an issue that I just cannot solve.

I have quite a few windows/dialogs that when I close them (and call dispose in the case where they derive from JDialog) they just aren't being GC'd.  YourKit reports that the only root to the GC is **"target of sun.awt.windows.WDialogPeer [JNI Global]"**.  There are some weak references too which seem to mostly come from MetalToolBarUI.  Presubably these only exist because of this one strong reference from WDialogPeer.

Has anyone seen this before - or can anyone give me an idea how and or/why WDialogPeer is holding onto my JDialogs/JFrames?  How can I clean it up?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6309407/261156) the same?

Comment: have you `dispose()`ed the child panel and frames?

Comment: Yes, dispose is called (and all call super) everywhere - I've double checked this.  Still reading the other post - thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for responses... I've tracked it down.  There was a JDialog being held as a member variable initialized in a constructor.  Although this was being disposed correctly - the deriving class was ALSO setting this member variable by newing it - so it was constructing two JDialogs, but only ever disposing one.