# Multiple JFrames for Game scenario

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm sorry if the title is worded a bit incorrectly.

I have recently started a new Game project, and have thought about the use of multiple `JFrame`s in Java.

The reason being is my game has 2 `JFrame`s:

1) Main Menu ( which is a singleton)

2) Battle.

Now the MainMenu `JFrame` will initialize the Battle `JFrame` on its own EDT, and then hide itself via `setVisible(false)`,when the game is over `setVisible(true)` can be called from Battle frame on the MainMenu frame singleton.

NB: The reason I did this was so MainMenus EDT could be reused for Battle `JFrame` thus there is only 1 EDT but 2 JFrames. To prevent the Battle frame from being active (after being closed because on same EDT)  I do `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Question:

Is this allowed or is there a better way?

I thought of a `CardLayout`, but because a new `GamePanel` will have to be created each time user presses Start `JButton` I cannot initiate a single instance and set that as the card

The reason for asking is I know when doing game programming in Java you do alot of things not consider good practice (like setting locations and overall not using a LayoutManager)

To help clarify in my MainMenu UI inside an actionPerformed() method of *Start Game* `JButton` I have:

```
 class MainMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        ...
            public void actionPerformed(..){
            NarutoGame narutoGame = null;
                narutoGame = new NarutoGame(...);

            narutoGame.setVisible(true);//running in MainMenu EDT
            //set this panels containing frame (MainMenu) to not visible
            }
        ...
   MainMenu getInstance() {
        ...
   }
 }
```

When the game is over in Battle JFrame:

```
class BattleField extends JFrame  {
    ...
    private void gameOver() {
        MainMenu.getInstance().setVisible(true);
        dispose();//dipsose of Battle JFrame
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you, but as I said I know its not good practice, but when creating games we often need to obscure these lines of good and bad practices to achieve what we need. As said in the question I cannot use a CardLayout, and I stated why

Comment: What do you by "own EDT"? There is only one EDT from which all components are painted

Comment: What's wrong with using two JPanel's and switching them out as you need to?

Comment: @MadProgrammer By own I mean MainMenu's its basically using its EDT for Battle Frame.

Comment: @MadProgrammer because a new `GamePanel` will have to be created each time user presses Start JButton I cannot initiate a single instance and set that as the card

Comment: @david So don't. Simple "remove" the menu pane and "add" you game pane, or use a controller pane for the game screen and add each new instance to it as you need?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: [`Buttons`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) is an example that simply invokes `removeAll()` in `resetGame()`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh man I guess thats a even better thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To foster the willing [suspension of disbelief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief), as well as for simple variety, games often push user interface design in novel ways. In practice, the appeal of multiple frames may *not* outweigh the risk. In addition to the well-known problems cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/230513), I would add the nightmare adduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310284/230513).

If `CardLayout` is inappropriate, [`Buttons`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) is an example that simply invokes `removeAll()` in `resetGame()`.

Comment: +1  thank you problem solved, actually opted for the latter (`removeAll()`) as I could do this dynamically (creating a new panel each time) thank you!!