# Adding JPanels to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to make a simple program with Java, Swing, that shows you a Window and by clicking the button "Start" it should show you a new panel with a login interface (enter username, password, login).

I've read a question asked here that says that it's better to use only one `JFrame` and it makes sense because I don't want to start a new window between clicking "start" button and going to the login interface. But, how should I do this? I've created two `JPanel` containers named `loginPanel` and `startPanel`, but I don't know how to set visible `loginPanel` when the application runs, and then by clicking a button (in `startPanel`) set visible `loginPanel` (and obviously stop showing `startPanel`).

I'm using the graphical Swing interface that comes with NetBeans (because the IDE have greyed the zone to edit the code by yourself, IDK why).

Could anyone give me a example of what I'd like to do?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130430/1133011) answer your question?

Comment: I think that code ([mre] ) would have been clearer and shorter than the attempt to describe it.

Comment: A log-in, which really only requires two fields each with a label, is typically much smaller in width and height than a 'start' panel or the main GUI. So for this I'd use 1 main `JFrame` for the 'start panel, in a `CardLayout` ready to switch to the main GUI, and a `JDialog` to display the login panel.

Comment: You asked: _Could anyone give me a example of what I'd like to do?_ I don't think that's how _stackoverflow_ works. I think that the idea behind _stackoverflow_ is to help people fix their code that doesn't work correctly for them. Search the Internet for ___java swing login page___ and you will find **many** examples of what you would _like to do_. Try to adapt those examples to your purposes and come back here when you hit a problem that you cannot find a resolution for.