# Destroy current class object and run same class through thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am calling a thread in which i am again calling the same class

```
TrafficMainGUI traffic=new TrafficMainGUI(storeValue);
traffic.setVisible(true);
```

but i want the previous class object to get destroy.How can i acheive this.

As TrafficMainGUI is a jFrame object.Please help??

Comment: "Destroy" means what? Closing the Frame?

Comment: I hope you're not creating/modifying or interacting with UI components outside of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: More details may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6310284/230513).

Answer (score 2):

To properly destroy a `JFrame`, you should [dispose](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) it.

```
previousTraffic.dispose();
TrafficMainGUI traffic=new TrafficMainGUI(storeValue);
traffic.setVisible(true);
```

From the documentation :

*`Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable.`*

Your question is quite vague about what you are doing with the threads.
As mentioned by @MadProgrammer, when you are working with `swing`, you should take into account the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). But to get a more specific help, you should provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

add this code:

```
traffic = new TrafficMainGUI(newValues);
```

traffic will be assigned by new Object, and the previous object will be replaced as `new` function is request new object in memory.

Comment: Assuming that no other object maintains a strong reference to the previous value of course

Answer (score 0):

To make your frame disappear just call

```
traffic.setVisible(true);
```

This however does not remove the instance of `TrafficMainGUI` you created. Since java has automatic garbage collection this object will be removed at some point of time automatically when all references that refer to it are not accessible. For example if your variable `traffic` is defined in method scope it becomes obsolete once your code exits the method. If not you can say `traffic = null;`. This will remove the reference.

You should note however that GC (garbage collector) lives its own life and can decide itself when to remove your object. It can decide not to remove it even forever. But you should not care about it.