# Memory leaking on JDialog closing

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, jdialog

I work on a Java application consisting (as yet) of a regular Window (JFrame) and a JDialog called by a menuitem in the first:

```
public class MainWindow {
    private JFrame frame;
    public MyDialog dialog;
    /* ... */
    private void initialize() {
         mnNew = new JMenuItem("New...");
         mnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             dialog = new MyDialog();
             }
         });
     }
}
```

And `MyDialog` is defined as follows:

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    public MyDialog() {
        /* ... */
        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                MyDialog.this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(MyDialog.this,
                                            WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                MainWindow.window.matchMaker = null;
            }
        });
        /* ... */
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but my Task Manager reports that each time I open and then close MyDialog, the program consumes more and more memory. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- reason is that [Top-Level Containers never will be GC'ed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime), [Top-Level Containers are based on peer from Native OS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)
- create [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) only one time, reuse that by `getContentPane.removeAll`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But shouldn't `MyDialog` be removed from memory after disposal and setting `dialog` variable to `null`? Anyway, it does nothing. Now I create MyDialog once in MainWindow constructor, setting its visibility to false. I make it visible with a function within MainWindow and invisible with another - in MyDialog, but memory is still leaking whenever I close and reopen the Dialog.

Comment: this is possible only by using static variables,

Answer (score 2):

Instanciate MyDialog once:

```
public class MainWindow {
   private JFrame frame;
   private final MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
```

removes `setVisible(true)` in MyDialog constructor.

To show the dialog just do `setVisible( true )`