# Changing layout/frame in response to a button press

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a little game on Java using the Swing components (Boggle-type game).
The way I have it set up right now, it basically opens up to the game right away - but I want to have a start up window with two buttons - "Tutorial" and "Play". I already have the functionality (my Tutorial button just opens a new Window with all the things on it) I'm just not sure how to create a second JFrame and then switch to it when I press Play (or rather, create a JFrame, then switch to the one I've already created when the JButton is pressed). I guess I could cause a new JFrame to open on the same location and the old one to become non-visible - but I was hoping for a simpler solution.

I also want to do this on completion of the game, switching again automatically to a little stat page - so any info will be appreciated.

This is what I have so far in case you guys want to see my code (I haven't yet hooked up the Enter key send the userWord to be validated and scored in my other classes, or filled in the tileGrid with Tile Objects, or the timer.... but that will all come later!)

```
public class Game implements Runnable {
public void run(){

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Boggle");
    frame.setLocation(500,200);

    // Input - holds typing box

    final JLetterField typingArea = new JLetterField(1); 
    typingArea.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    typingArea.setEditable(true);
    typingArea.setFocusable(true);
    typingArea.requestFocusInWindow(); //also this request isn't being granted.. 
                                       //if anyone could explain why i would love you
                                       // I want the focus on the TextField on startup


    frame.add(typingArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    typingArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) { // enter key is pressed
                String userWord = typingArea.getText().toLowerCase();
                typingArea.setText("");

            }
        }
    });


    final JLabel status = new JLabel("Running...");

    // Main playing area

    GridLayout tileGrid = new GridLayout(4,4);
    final JPanel grid = new JPanel(tileGrid);
    frame.add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Reset button
    final JPanel control_panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(control_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    final ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("Instructions.png", "My Instructions...");
    final JButton info = new JButton("Help");
    info.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final JFrame infoFrame = new JFrame("Tutorial");
            infoFrame.setLocation(500,50);
            JLabel tutorialImg = new JLabel(img);
            int w = img.getIconWidth();
            int h = img.getIconHeight();
            infoFrame.setSize(w, h);
            infoFrame.add(tutorialImg);
            infoFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    control_panel.add(info);

    // Put the frame on the screen
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Game());
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of [second JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), [your concept is heading to OutOfMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)
2. use [JFrame.pack(after switch betweens Cards in CardLayout)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) if you want to change JFrames bounds on runtime,

Comment: thanks @mKorbel  im still fairly new to programming and I wasnt sure what the relevance of the link in "heading to OutOfMemory" was.

Card Layout does seem to be what I'm looking for though

Comment: your JButton always created a new JFrame, with JLabel and Image as Icon, and those Object in this form stays in JVM memory and increasing with a new JFrame