# How to dispose of the JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, dispose, jfilechooser

Every time the button is pressed, does it create a new JFileChooser object? Is it possible to dispose it, or does java do that automatically for me?

```
public void buttonPressed(){
    JFileChooser chooser = null;
    LookAndFeel previousLF = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(previousLF);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | InstantiationException | ClassNotFoundException e) {}

    File location = new File("C:\\");
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(location);
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Your Directory");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java automatically disposes of unused memory using a Garbage collector, so yes.  It will dispose of your JFileChooser object automatically.

Also yes, each time your button is pressed, if you call buttonPressed, a new JFileChooser will be created.  This is acceptable.

Comment: [hmmm disagree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)

Comment: The amount of time it takes to create a file chooser class is so gnomic ant enough to consider using a lazy loading approach,,but keeping the created instance if you think it's going to be reused. If even set up a global one in the past and configured it as needed

Answer (score 0):

The Garbage collector should take care of deleting your JFlieChooser object. You can read more about how the Garbage collector works [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)