# Restart a JFrame after dispose

Tags: java, swing, frame, dispose, restart

I have a problem with a Frame that I want to restart after an operation.
In specific, below the start of the `Frame`:

```
public static void startHome() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new HomeGUI();
                frame.setVisible(true); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Below the Frame:

```
public HomeGUI() throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ico_path));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 669, 516);
// etc...
```

Below my actual code for the restart, but doesn't work:

```
frame.dispose();
startHome();
```

Processing stops before to enter in `run()` method.
I tried to set `frame = null` before `invokeLater` and after `dispose()`, but doesn't work.

Thank you to all

Comment: Your HomeGUI class must extend JFrame. Can you provide code of your HomeGUI class.

Comment: when you call the dispose method, you probably saw that the Frame was closed.. the dispose close the frame and stop the process of the thread (the run method), so there's nothing at the object that holds Frame (if you wrote Frame1 f = new Frame1(), so f is then garbage).. you have to create a new instance after the dispose

Comment: @Elior [Top-Level Containers never will be GC'ed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1):

1. there are two ways (without any intentions to restart whatever) to (re)use

   - `setIconImage()`
   - `CardLayout`
2. be sure `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`; to terminate current JVM
3. proper `LayoutManager`, `JComponent`(s) must returns `PreferredSize` back to `JFrame`, then call

   - `JFrame.pack()`
   - `JFrame.setLocation()`
   - `JFrame.setVisisble(true)`
   - as last code lines in constructor
   - because I can't found any reason to use AbsoluteLayour e.g. `setBounds(100, 100, 669, 516);`
4. `dispose()` or `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);` is the same as `setVisible(false)`, you can get all `Top-Level Containers` from current JVM by iterating in arrays of `Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();`

Comment: I don't understand the effective changes to be applied for my code...

Point 2: it's already used;
Point 3: where I must insert this lines?
Point 4: I don't understand...

Comment: whats real reason for "restart". to `Point 3: where I must insert this lines?` ---> last code lines after all GUI is created, `Point 4: I don't understand see my comment` follows link in my comment to `Elior Top-Level Containers never will be GC'ed`