# How to detect if one swing window is above another one

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have several unrelated `JFrames` opened in my app. And on app exit I should remember the preferences of all of them to restore them the same view they was before exit.

The problem is when these frames are located one above another, they should be restored in the same order. Another way the smaller `frames` would not be visible under bigger ones.

**QUESTION:** How can I detect the deep location each of `frames` in this case?

**UPD:** I detect this case by comparing the `frames' location/size pairs`, but I still do not how to resolve my issue.

**UPD2:** Note: the  `several jframes ui` is not default state. `One JFrame` shown by default, but user **can** use several if he **want**. My question **is not** about `how to make single JFrame`, but `how to operate with several ones`.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: *"I can't find the my question' answer on your link.."*  That is why it is a **comment**, not an **answer.**  But -1 for your (apparent) intention to foist such a monstrous GUI on your innocent users (both of them).

Comment: @SeniorJD : You can simply use [__Window.isFocusableWindow()__](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isFocusableWindow()), to check as to which `Jframe` is at top. I hope this can work :-)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without restoring to JNI/JNA

Comment: It would not be overly reliable either. On X11 some window managers refuse to cooperate when an application tries to micromanage the windows.

Comment: @AndrewThompson hard day? :)

Comment: @nIcEcOw please write your comment as an answer, it helps me with a gr8 idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [Window.isFocusableWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isFocusableWindow%28%29), to check as to which `JFrame` lies on top of all others.

Though I will also insist on not using more than a single `JFrame`, for any application :-)

Comment: It is close to my real solution: I've created the global `FocusListener` and added it for every of my JFrame. When the window is under focus, it is added to a list (or setting the last index, if it is already there), then, using this list, I detect the `Z-Order` of windows. Thanks!

Comment: *for any application :-)* What about File Explorer? Don't you use several of its Windows at the time?

Comment: @SeniorJD : Never worked on such things before, but what ever I have experienced so far, never felt a need of more than one `JFrame`. I use to play games online on [Game Ranger](http://www.gameranger.com/), and their multiple windows always use to annoy me :-). JDialog can be chosen instead of a `JFrame`, as that will maintain some relation of `parent-child`, which can help in various situations.

Comment: See the UPD2 please. The several JFrames is just `if-you-want` feature, but not `must have`.

Answer (score 2):

> QUESTION: How can I detect the deep location each of frames in this
>   case?
>
> UPD: I detect this case by comparing the frames' location/size pairs,
>   but I still do not how to resolve my issue.

- you can to loop inside arrays of Top-Level Containers

.

```
  Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();
  for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
        if (wins[i] instanceof JFrame) {
            wins[i].wheteverMethodImplementedInConcreteAPI;
        } //else if ... JDialog, JWindow, e.i. AWT Containers
  }
```

.

> Hmm.. I can't find the my question' answer on your link
>   actually...Except the bad bad practise to use several JFrames :)

.

- see [Remove Top-Level Container on Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime), then there are

  1. use `CardLayout` instead of bunch of `JFrames`, without any popup windows
  2. use `CardLayout` instead of bunch of `JFrames` and for another popup window to use `JDialog`()/`JWindow`(`JTextComponents` aren't editable)
  3. use `CardLayout` instead of bunch of `JFrames` and for another popup window to use `JDialog`()/`JWindow`(`JTextComponents` aren't editable) with `CardLayout` for multiple switching betweens view in popup container, note usage `Xxx.pack()` is required for proper sizing after card is switched
  4. set `JFrame` as  parent for `JDialog()`/`JWindow()`, then parent v.s. child are question of `isVisible`, `isDisplayable`, etc, and rest events implemented in `WindowEvent`

Comment: `you can to loop inside arrays of Top-Level Containers` Yes, I can. And what would I be able to get there?

Comment: And what would I be able to get there? == Window[] wins = Window.getWindows(); please to see my question edited, really forgot add this code line

Comment: Yes, I mean what info about their `Z-order` can I get from this `array`? And how?

Comment: wihtout chainging parent v.s. childs there aren't ordering of JFrames, in (AFAIK in another PL too) you need to hold this index, increasing, maybe in protected methods, but comment by @Andrew Thompson is about good practicies in all PL (created on_screen GUI)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getComponentZOrder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component%29) to get the z-index of the frames and set it using [setComponentZOrder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component%29).

Comment: From the which object should I use the method? The `JFrames` are `unrelated`, they do not have the same `parent` or the link to each other.

Comment: I don't think this can be applied to frames

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html So JFrame inherits Component

Comment: `getComponentZOrder` takes a `Component` parameter which is consider a child of the container calling it... *"Returns the z-order index of the component inside the container. The higher a component is in the z-order hierarchy, the lower its index. The component with the lowest z-order index is painted last, above all other child components."* - Or I will accept a working example

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Or I will accept a working example"*  Hear, hear..  Let the code do the talking.