# How to check if a window is on top without focus in Java

Tags: java, swing, testing

I have two Windows and I want to check if one of them is on front but do not have the focus. I have to write a test because we had that bug in our Software a few days ago. So the Window on top does not have the focus and I it is also not active.

UPD: I can not use `Window.isFocusableWindow()` or anything else related to the focus of a window!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if one swing window is above another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879308/how-to-detect-if-one-swing-window-is-above-another-one)

Comment: I already read that answer but I can not use any of the solution. I think my problem is more compilcated because regular it is not possible to have a window on top wihout the focus.

Comment: Z-Ordering of windows is the OS's task so I think you're out of luck from within Java. The only way I'm aware (if you're using Windows) is a DLL created with VB, C#, C/C++ that uses [`GetTopWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633514(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) and access it via [JNI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).

Comment: hm.. thank you so far.  It is not mandatory that my test runs on a Windows machine so I think that is not an option.