# Java, JDialog: Returning value after dispose()

Tags: java, swing

first of all, i don't speak correct english, and sorry for that!

I am making a stock system in Java, and it's working, but i have a doubt about the correct use of `dispose()` from JDialog instance.

My code:

```
public Usuario getUsuario() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
    return new VentanaConfigurarPrivilegios(new Usuario(textField.getText(), new String(passwordField.getPassword()))).getUsuario();
}
```

this function works and returns a new `Usuario` from the new Instance of `VentanaConfigurarPrivilegios` calling to `getUsuario()`, but the doubt is about the last 2 lines, i'm disposing the JDialog, and after, is passing a text from textFields, it work fine, but i'm not sure that i am doing this in a correct way, and i would not like that the code fails when is using.

Again, sorry for my english!! Thanks.

Comment: Is the dialog declared modal?  I guess it must be if the code is working as you expect.  For better help (better than guesses) sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You don't need to call dispose() at all normally. And *if* you call dispose(), all it does is release the native window handle, saving some memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is that once you dispose() a dialog it is eligible for garbage collection, so would garbage collection ever happen before you are able to access the text from the text fields displayed on the dialog.

I don't think it would be a problem but just in case you can reorder your code:

```
this.setVisible(true);
VentanaConfigurarPrivilegios data = new Vent...(...);
this.dispose();
return data;
```

Comment: That's not how GC works. As long as there's a reference to the object, the object is not GC'd.

Comment: I agree with @Darkhogg. All `dispose()` does is to release *native* resources. That's it. The JDialog object itself and all of its components are still available to be queried as long as there exists valid references to it.

Comment: Thanks for repply, a last question, que variable "data" when i call "dispose()", also be deleted?

Comment: @user2928577 I think that quite common issue with out of memory e.i. [if I remember correctly rest is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19598199/714968), read comments and follows link in my comment too

Comment: Thanks guys, I was over thinking things.