# Optional way to close a dialog window

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm using a custom JFrame to implement a simple dialog in a Java application I'm working on.

After the user pushes the 'Apply' button in the window, it should close.

What would be the most conventional way to do this? Is `setVisible(false)` inside the class the best way? Is there any way more recommended?

Comment: What's wrong with `JOptionPane` or `JDialog`?

Comment: You want to close the dialog or frame?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Close a small JFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close a window in Swing like [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) or [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) you have two options.

#### Call `dispose()`

Just call [dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) method:

> ```
> public void dispose()
> ```
>
> Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its
>   subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources
>   for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will
>   be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable.

For instance:

```
frame.dispose();
dialog.dispose();
```

---

#### Dispatch a `WINDOW_CLOSING` event

You can dispatch a new [WindowEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html) like this:

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
dialog.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(dialog, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

If the window has attached a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) it will be notified. If the frame's (or dialog's) default close operation is set then this action will be performed. The possible close operations are:

- [`DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE) (defined in `WindowConstants`): Don't do anything;
  require the program to handle the operation in the windowClosing
  method of a registered WindowListener object.
- [`HIDE_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#HIDE_ON_CLOSE) (defined in `WindowConstants`): Automatically hide the
  frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
- [`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and
  dispose the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener
  objects.
- [`EXIT_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE) (defined in `JFrame` and not available for `JDialog`): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.

Comment: Thanks :) For this purpose I'll just use `dispose()`.

Comment: +1   [but dispose() == setVisible(false)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime) in the case that/if is there one JFrame/JDialog/JWindow already visible on the screen (can be hide by setVisible(false)), note otheriwse there is last turn of lights, last one terminating current JVM

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. Setting the window to not visible will simply hide it but it will still be running in the background (JFrame/InternalFrame). You can use JDialog (See JOptionPane as an example) to create temporary frames which are truly closed when clicking on one of the buttons. You can also retrieve the selected option when the user closed the window (here : [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)). You can also forcibly close a window by firing an event to close it, like so:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(
                    new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)
             )
```

Inside an actionlistener for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple operations which can be performed when you close a JFrame.

Suppose you have a JFrame

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

This one exits the JVM when closed.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This one just hides the JFrame.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

This one disposes the JFrame.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate

And the default is do nothing.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```