# Is it safe to dispose a JDialog in a try block, and then continue executing code in a matching finally block?

Tags: java, swing, dispose, jdialog, try-finally

I have tried searching around for this question, as I imagine it must have been asked at some point, but this was the closest thing I could find [Remove Top-Level Container on Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime).

My question is, is it safe execute code in a `JDialog`, after having called `dispose()` on that dialog, if the dispose is done in a `try` and the executing code is done in a `finally`?

Here is an example to demonstrate what I am asking:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class DisposeTestDialog extends JDialog {
    private final String somethingToPrint;

    public DisposeTestDialog(String somethingToPrint) {
        this.somethingToPrint = somethingToPrint;
    }

    public void showAndDispose() {
        setVisible(true);
        // Do something
        setVisible(false);
        try {
            dispose();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println(somethingToPrint);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DisposeTestDialog dialog = new DisposeTestDialog("Can this be safely printed?");
                dialog.showAndDispose();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

From what I know of the `dispose()` process, and `finally` blocks, I would say it should work fine, if not a great idea. Indeed running the above code does successfully print.

Is it possible though that a GC could start in between the `try`/`finally` and cause some issue?

Comment: If you need for your class to be persistent, don't extend a JDialog.  Use a JDialog.  Only extend a Swing Component when you want to override one of the component methods.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Yeah that was really only for this example. My actual use case is vastly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as you access only non-graphical objects such as string from your example.

Comment: So you're saying as long as I don't do something that would access part of the Dialog's framework, then I should be fine?