# How to get rid of "dead" windows in Java?

Tags: java, swing, dispose

I am working with some legacy code. During execution, that code creates multiple windows and disposes them. However, they are still reachable and i.e. calling `java.awt.Window.getWindows()` returns a large array of `java.awt.Window`, `javax.swing.JFrame`, `javax.swing.JDialog` and the like, all of which have their name starting with "dead-". This now increasingly becomes a problem.

So here are my questions: Am I correct, that the 'dead-' prefix of the name is created by the System?
What can I do to properly dispose old windows such that they are no longer reachable and returned by `java.awt.Window.getWindows()`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide a piece of code showing how the legacy code currently create / dispose the windows.

Comment: Top-level conbtainers aren't GC'ed, then all are accessible untill current JVM exists, [more here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime), result should be to reuse reasonable numbers of Containers (reduced to max number of container that can be visible on the screen at one time)

Comment: those containers aren't dead, only containers that returns false from isDisplayable

Comment: there are accesible all JOptionPanes, but by casting from its parent - JDialog

Comment: See also this related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6309407/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following code inside the project:

```
private void disposeWindow(final java.awt.Window window) {
    SwingEnvironment.runOnEventDispatchingThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            window.dispose();
            window.setVisible(false);
            window.removeNotify();

            String oldName = window.getName();
            if (oldName == null) {
                oldName = "unnamed";
            }

            if (!oldName.startsWith("dead-")) {
                window.setName("dead-" + oldName);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So this is the reason the windows where named 'dead-'.

However they were properly disposed and still showed up in the Windows Array that is returned by the `java.awt.Window.getWindows()`. To get rid of them, I had to create a separate `ThreadGroup` and create a separate `AppContext` via `SunToolkit.createNewAppContext();`. Disposing that AppContext also disposed the Windows properly in my case. See also http://kingsfleet.blogspot.de/2009/10/how-to-have-more-than-one-instance-of.html.