# Maybe a good reason to use multiple JFrames, if not open to suggestions

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm developing an application for a deposit ATM. Almost everyone has used one of these at least once in their life so it's safe to say you know what I'm talking  about.

I'm currently doing the GUI and I think I should use multiple JFrames.

My reasons:

1. Each frame is set to respond to certain, different conditions - smart card reader sends a signal, timeout occurs, click occurs, different parts of the machine send various signals to which the app must respond and display an appropriate message
2. Since this is an embedded device the user has zero ability to interact with the os of the machine beyond using this one program. I think this sets aside considerations of esthethics - multiple windows in taskbar.
3. The Fullscrean mode does a great job of conceiling everything else going on in the background.

What I dislike:

I get a screen flicker when switching from one frame to another. This might not be related to the general topic of the question and might just be because I'm disposing of frames everytime the program switches away from them instead of setting them to be invisible.

Any thoughts on the subject are welcome.

Comment: It's no real advantage to use multiple `JFrame`s, when you can use a single one and have multiple content panes for it.

Comment: Eventually, if you really like the multiple frame design, you can take a look at `JInternalFrame` and `JDesktop`.

Comment: I don't think internal frames are the way to do it - it's not an MDI.

Comment: I get a screen flicker when switching from one frame to another. == hasn't something with multiple instances ...., [lwrong dispose == setVisible for JVM that is still alive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)

Comment: you can to use multiple instances instead of CardLayout, but you'll going crazy from this design

Comment: Each frame is set to respond to certain, different conditions == JMenuItem with CardLayout (with JFrame.pack() as last code line for every Cards)

Comment: Agree with @mKorbel..  Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: So far CardLayout seems the way to go. I would like to select your comment as an answer, mKobel, but I can't. If you add it to the answers I will.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a single `JFrame`, and have multiple `JPanel`s for the various "screens" you want to show. To change "screen", just remove from the `JFrame` the `JPanel` currently shown and add the new one.

EDIT:
To make the switch, you can use `CardLayout` as LayoutManager of your frame. It shows one panel at a time and allows you to easily switch between them.

Comment: *"just remove from the `JFrame` the `JPanel` currently shown and add the new one."*  This is exactly the type of job that **`CardLayout`** was made for!

Comment: @AndrewThompson You're rigth! I didn't remeber it existed!

Answer (score 1):

It's no real advantage to use multiple `JFrame`s, when you can use a single one and have multiple content panes for it.

This should prevent any useless flickering and make sure that only one of your "screens" is visible at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of this but I don't think I understand. Could you please provide a link describing the method in more detail?

Comment: `JFrame.setContentPane()` can be used to replace all the contents of the frame with a new panel, so instead of multiple frames you'd just use multiple content panes (essentially JPanels).

Comment: @Kayaman (2nd. sentence) I'm doubt it about in Java6/7/8 edges