# Swing application becomes unresponsive after keeping operating for about 6 hours continuously

Tags: java, performance, swing, automated-tests

I have to say that I am not familiar with Swing technology. I am doing test automation on a Swing application. The problem I encountered was when I ran my tests automatically overnight, the application became unresponsive after a certain period of time and then tests failed. I recorded the time in test log, the period was mostly around 6 hours.

The application was still working but very slowly. There was no out of memory exception thrown. So I reckon it could be something wrong with the implementation of app using Swing. And maybe because the app keeps running so garbage collecting cannot catch up?

I couldn't find much information by Google. Could anyone who had similar experience shed some lights on the direction to solve this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to run some analytics (profile) over the code and see where the memory is been trapped.  Does some search into a good profiler

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6310284/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Try connecting to the application using JConsole and leave it running for the duration of the test. Check the memory heap usage chart. If you see the see saw line slowly rising, you have a memory leak somewhere.

There are tools to examine the heap, like IBM's [Heap Analyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091).