# Find out JDialog instance is already disposed or not

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Do we have a method or way to find out a JDialog instance is already disposed or not.

Comment: `isVisible`?  `isDisplayable`?

Comment: Yes.But some times JDialog call dispose many times.Some dialog call it when closing it.So if we call GC it will call again.Problem is we keep a log of disposed dialogs.It is a text file.Some dialog log more that one.So need to avoid logging if dispose already called.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a form of premature optimization.  If you're worried about dialogs, keep a reference to a small number of dialogs and change their content as needed.  But I would only worry about it if the app. was throwing an `OutOfMemoryError` and even then, I'd be looking at other areas of the app. first.

Comment: @Prabhath by default all Top-Level containers are always accesible for current JVM, [for more info see about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)