# What resource are JFrames consuming?

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, jvm

I'm running some stress tests that require a bunch of jframes to be created, and am running into some serious performance issues after ~25 jframes have been created, it starts to take 5-10 seconds **per JFrame** to create and dispose, which seems terribly outside of expectations.

Tested on a Macbook Pro running Mojave and Java jdk1.8.0_111

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    fun createFrame(): JFrame {
        val frame = JFrame("FrameDemo")
        System.out.println("created frame" + frame)
        frame.setSize(1000, 600)
        frame.isVisible = true
        return frame
    }

    val frames = mutableListOf<JFrame>()
    for(i in 0..35) SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait { frames.add(createFrame()) }

    for(i in 1..50) {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        var frame: JFrame? = null
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait {
            frame = createFrame()
        }
        System.out.println("started in ${System.currentTimeMillis()-start}")
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait {
            frame!!.dispose()
        }
        System.out.println("done in ${System.currentTimeMillis()-start}")
    }

    for(frame in frames)
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait { frame.dispose() }
}
```

The first loop creates a bunch of JFrames just so they exist, and the second loop creates+destroys jframes to collect some performance numbers.

If I comment out the first loop, then each jframe takes O(100ms) to create+destroy.  With the first loop, the same create+destroy operation takes two orders of magnitude longer O(10000ms).

At first, I thought maybe I was running out of memory, but there doesn't appear to be any GC/CPU pressure and increasing `-Xmx` dosen't appear to improve the situation.  None of my other metrics (eg. iops) seem impacted, but my whole machine does feel slow as a snail.

What is going on here?  Other non-swing applications (sublime, chrome, etc) seem able to have many large windows open no problem, so I don't think it is anything inherent to the machine.  Is there a setting that will allow me to avoid the performance cliff?

Comment: Serious question: should we be tagging Kotlin programs as "Java"? Because I can't really make heads or tails of the above code, so I'm not sure the Java tag is useful.

Comment: @markspace This is likely a question about the underlying Java libraries involved.

Comment: You may need to [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513); see also [*Remove Top-Level Container on Runtime*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6309407/230513).